# Choosing line ending with libxml2

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix, libxml2

I try to generate some xml files (`TMX`) on our servers.

The servers are Solaris SPARC servers, but the destination of the files are some legacy Windows CAT Tools.

The CAT-Tool requires `CR+LF` line endings as is the default on Windows. Writing the files with libxml2, using `xmlWriter` is easy and works quite well. But I haven't figured out a way to force the lib to emit `CR+LF` instead of the Unix standard `LF`. The lib only seem to support the line ending of the platform it runs on.

Has somebody found a way to generate files with another line ending than the default of the platform it runs on. Actually my workaround is to open the written file and writing a new file with the changed line ending using a simple `C` loop. That works, but it is annoying to have such a unnecessary step in our chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but from [xmlsave](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlsave.html), I can see two possibilities

- [xmlSaveToBuffer](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlsave.html#xmlSaveToBuffer): save to a buffer, convert to CR/LF and write it out yourself.
- [xmlSaveToIO](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlsave.html#xmlSaveToIO): register an `iowrite` callback and convert to CF/LF while writing in your callback function

Maybe, there are other options, but I haven't found them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that when I come back to work. I wanted to avoid working with a memory built structure (the files can be huge) as I largely prefer the sequential fire and forget mode of the `xmlWriter` object.

Answer (score 2):

> The CAT-Tool requires CR+LF line endings as is the default on Windows.

FWIW, that means the CAT-Tool has a broken XML parser.  It shouldn't care about this, as [the the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends) says:

> To simplify the tasks of applications, the XML processor **must** behave as if it normalized all line breaks ... by translating both the two-character sequence #xD #xA and any #xD that is not followed by #xA to a single #xA character.

I know often these things are out of our control, but if you can lean on the CAT-Tool vendor to fix their software, it could become a more future-proof solution.

Comment: It is broken, no doubt, but I can't change it. It's in a big orgnisation and it involves around 5000 work stations. I'm only a producer of one of the components the translators work with. Furthermore, I said mainly the CAT-tool but there are also several other legacy components that would choke. As said, we expunge and change step by step but it will take a long time until everything is fixed. I asked that question to remove at least one step of the crud we have.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code (as of April 2013), libxml2 just puts "\n" into the output stream. At least, when writing dtd-part of a document. Therefore, re-encoding the stream on the fly is the only option to get "\r\n" as result.

If you were lucky (as me) and your tool run on Windows, you could open the file in the text mode, and the OS would do recoding for you.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I supposed it was. Unfortunately the program runs on Solaris-SPARC servers in the back-end and are destined for a CAT-Tool on Windows PC's.